# C++, RapidXML: function to get total of siblings nodes

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

**for example:**

```
<something>
   <x/>
   <x/>
   <y/>
   <z/>
</something>
```

It must return 2, I thought about using, for this example:

```
int Get_total_x(){
   int total=0;
   for(xml_node<> *x=root_node->first_node("x"); x; x=x->next_sibling()){
      total++;
   };
   return total;
};
```

Does RapidXML has a especific function for that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with rapidxml anyway I just gone through the code and I found

```
inline std::size_t count_children(xml_node<Ch> *node)
```

in `rapidxml_utils.hpp`

Comment: Tanks, but that returns me the ammount of all the children inside the node, in my xml doc i not only have x, also i have y and z for example, i only want those who match with my search (x).

Comment: can u provide a sample xml file that you are trying to parse?

Comment: I edited the post whit a example.of what i am trying to do.

Comment: there is no y & z children in the example and am sure `cout_children` will work for you if it was the xml format

Comment: I edited the post again, as you can see, there is **four child nodes** but only **two are x** that are what i am searching, `count_children()` will return me four.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file section, I presume, is not valid: the `<x>, <x>, <y>, <z>` elements aren't closed and are not empty.
You should write `<x/>, <x/>, <y/>, <z/>`

Comment: Its cannot  be consider as the answer to this question.